# How to hyperparameter tuning GridSearchCV in Bayesian ridge regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, bayesian, hyperparameters

I tried to find the best parameter on Bayesian ridge regression with default value but I would like to you GridSearchCV on this estimator

Should I set it as below or not?

```
bay_params = {'alpha_init':[1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.9],
              'lambda_init': [1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5, 1e-6, 1e-9]}
a = GridSearchCV(estimator=BayesianRidge(), param_grid = bay_params, cv = 3, n_jobs=-1)
a.fit(normalized_x_train[sel_features],y_train)
```

Is that make sense?

Comment: Anyway, the results are quiet same as the default.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. If the results are very similar then maybe you should try another model? Without knowing more about your data and problem, it's hard to advise further.

Comment: I run on multiple regressor (ada,rf,bagging,grad,svr,bayes_ridge,elastic_net,lasso) I found out that, Baye, is the best R2.

Anyways, I think this issue corresponds to the statistic subject. As we have the prior probability on distribution.

Answer (score -1):

you can use 'optuna' Library to find the best hyperparams

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).